# Blank icons after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 on Unity

Tags: unity, 18.04, icons, themes, unity-tweak-tool

This happened right after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 on my father's PC from Ubuntu 16.04.

[image: Icons are blank]

Changing the icon pack or the GTK theme does not work.  The only way I get to see the icons again is by disabling auto-coloring based on wallpaper using the Unity Tweak Tool.

Does anyone know why and how it happened?  It'd be great if the icons are visible again with the auto-coloring enabled.

[image: Icons are restored after using a static color]